# Play video in java from InputStream

Tags: java, windows, video

Does anyone know what I should use to play a video in Java, from an InputStream?
I get the video from a SOAP message, and I don't want to save it to the hard disk, I just want to play it once and then release it.

I have tried using JMF, I downloaded it, but it doesn't even install.
What other free (open-source) alteratives are there in Java?

Oh, and I need to play any formats of video for which there are codecs installed (if it plays in Windows Media Player, it should play in the library I am using).

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/).  See the MediaViewer object for source code showing how to do it.  With Xuggler pretty much all codecs are supported out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

JMF is the way to go.

Get JMF to install.

Comment: +1: It's not like JMF doesn't meet the requirements, discarding it because of teething problems is silly.

Comment: I'm also disregarding it because it's no longer supported. The installer (or part of it) is a 16 bit app. We're almost in 2010, geez...
And I also need it to support whatever codecs are installed in Windows. Can it do that without additional configuration?

Answer (score 1):

JMF doesn't need/want to be installed. Just find the JAR and put it on the classpath. Works for me.

Comment: Where can I get the JAR file?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html . If you get a .ZIP, unpack it. If you get an .EXE, execute it. To get all the video stuff you'll also need the Windows Performance Pack.

Comment: OK, then I give up. Chances are, it doesn't fully support all formats supported by MPlayer anyway, so you might be disappointed if you got it running.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I found FMJ, a library that uses JMF and it works, but I don't know how to get it to work from InputStream. It only works if I save the file to the hard disk, and then pass the filename as a parameter.
http://fmj-sf.net/

Comment: Does it come with source code? Figure out what it's doing! Since JMF is doing most of the work, it's probably little more than a wrapper.